# How to add login/logout link in cakephp 2.x layout?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am creating a website with cakephp 2.0. I want to add login/logout link in my layout. 
For logged in user only logout link should be visible and for guest user, only login link should be visible. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the AuthComponent for user sessions, you can check whether a user session exists with the static `user` method. This is also covered in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user). For example:

```
if (AuthComponent::user()):
  // The user is logged in, show the logout link
  echo $this->Html->link('Log out', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
else:
  // The user is not logged in, show login link
  echo $this->Html->link('Log in', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
endif;
```

Comment: I tried this solution for the first time but I think AuthComponent::user() object persists the user details in cookies. So once logged in, the user will always see the logout link until the browser cookies are cleared. Do you have any idea or solution for this? ???

Comment: @JohnHogan `Unexpected if` means that you forgot to terminate a previous statement prior to the if.

Answer (score 2):

Hey here is how I did it in cakePHP 3.x

```
 <?php
if($this->request->Session()->read('Auth')) {
   // user is logged in, show logout..user menu etc
   echo $this->Html->link(__('Log Out'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout']); 
} else {
   // the user is not logged in
   echo $this->Html->link(__('Log in'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

call the logout function like

```
function logout(){
    $this->Cookie->destroy('Your Cookie name goes here');
    if($this->Auth->logout($this->data)){
        //auto redirected
    }
}
```